# props property not seen in react component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting to learn react and am currently using Visual Studio 2017 to code a basic hello world web app. My index.html file is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="./dist/app-bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

while my app.tsx file is as follows (app.tsx is transpiled to ./dist/app-bundle.js):

```
declare var require: any

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Welcome to dsdasd!!</h1>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The above two files work fine. However, when I try to use the props property (shown below in the modified app.tsx) in the Hello class, the transpiler shows errors,

```
declare var require: any

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Welcome to {this.props.message}!!</h1>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello message = "some message"/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

ERROR: `TS2339: Property 'message' does not exist on type '()'`

How can I resolve this error? My understanding is that the props and state are always available in a react component. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces before and after `=` that has come in the last line?

Comment: @Masious, I did that but the error remains ... do spaces matter?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the props interface for a Typescript + React component:

```
interface Props {
  message: string;
}

class Hello extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Welcome to {this.props.message}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I still get the same error ... is there anything else that I might be missing?

Comment: @estus, this does seem to be correct ... though I did recompile the project and the error still remains

Comment: @mettleap The problem is that you use `require`. `require` should be used only when you want modules to be type-unsafe. Use `import`.